# "and Scripture cannot be broken—John 10:35b, what Jesus is saying?

Tags: john

Is this  a "side remark, or an axiomatic Major Premise?

What impacts & implications does it have for hermeneutic?

John 10:35b,

"—**and Scripture cannot be broken**"(ESV)(και ου δύναται λυθήναι η γραφή)

Answer (score 3):

I am not really sure what direction you are wanting this to go, but yes, this is a parenthetical statement. The implications this has for hermeneutics is that scripture is absolute in its meaning and it can never fail, it can never be overturned, overpowered, or destroyed. All scripture is the product of the mind of God with no human contribution to its content and therefore, scripture will mean only what God intends for it to mean; anything else is a perversion. This also means that revealed symbols can only be defined by scripture, never by human rational interpretation.

Comment: Does this word of Jesus address to academies and churches over the major theological-fallacies on Soteriology, namely OSAS vs. "Can Lose the Salvation?

Comment: I would accept that as an axiom.

Answer (score 2):

**"Scripture cannot be broken" -John 10:35b**

Text:
**"—and Scripture cannot be broken"**(ESV)(και ου δύναται λυθήναι η γραφή)

**1. A "side remark, or an axiomatic Major Premise?**

It is a short and parenthetical, nonetheless incredibly significant statement from the lips of Jesus. It is axiomatic with all-time significance, and Jesus, with this one sweeping statement answers to all the arguments against the unity, authority, and the inerrancy of   Scripture.**  ***Jesus said it all -"Scripture cannot be broken!"***

**2. Notes on the text:**

**V 35**: "If he called them gods to whom **the word of God** came—and **Scripture** **cannot be broken**" (ESV)

- **"The Word of God"** means the word proceeded from God, though it may have come human
  chanel, nonetheless not from man.
- **the Scripture (ἡ γραφή)** has a specific significance. It denotes Divine words **" which have been written.**" Of the many things God has said, but by the inspiration of the
  Holy Spirit only what needs to be set down were written for us.

  e.g. John 16: 12 -I still have many things to say to you, but you cannot bear them
  now.

  ```
      John 20:30 -Now Jesus did many other signs in the presence of the disciples, 
           which are not written in this book.

      Revelation 10: 4“Seal up what the seven thunders have said, and do not write it 
          down.”
  ```
- **cannot**(=cannot possibly  **οὐ δύναται**) with **οὐ**-negative absolute
  and affirmative means a strong negative.
- **break**(**λυθῆναι**) -**λύω** loose, untie, set free, destroy, break up, abolish. It
  also has a theological significance denoting it is the act of those who were appointed and placed in holy office
  to communicate the Word of God, but not to tamper with it, such "practice" is not
  acknowledged in Heaven.
  cf. Matt. 16:19; 18:18 -"whatever you loose on earth shall be loosed in heaven."

**Sum up**:

**a**. Jesus is saying, every word of God written in the Scripture stands immutable and indestructible in its
eternal verity. No word of it be
dissolved by any human authority. Scripture will not be affected by criticism or
denial
of theology.

**b**. Scriptural warnings against "breaking the Scripture"

- You shall not add to the word that I command you, nor take from it, that you may keep
  the commandments of the LORD your God that I command you. (Deut. 4:2)
- I warn everyone who hears the words of the prophecy of this book: if anyone adds to
  them, God will add to him the plagues described in this book, 19and if anyone takes
  away from the words of the book of this prophecy, God will take away his share in the
  tree of life and in the holy city, which are described in this book.(Rev. 22: 18-19)

**3. Major "Breakings" recorded in the Bible, and Church history:**
(not an exhaustive list)

**(1). Genesis 3:1- 6** ** -The first and the original "breaking of the Word of God,"** resulting devastation to "cosmos" & humanity and costing God dearly!

-**The serpent** to the Eve,

*“Did God actually say ‘You shall not eat
of any tree in the garden’?” .. “You will not surely die. For God knows that when
you eat of it your eyes will be opened, and you will be like God, knowing good and
evil.”*

**(2) Mark 7:8-14:** -Jesus calls their acts of disregard & breaking the Scripture is from
devil (John 8:44 -You are of your father the devil).

-"You leave the commandment of God and hold to the tradition of men.”
“You have a fine way of rejecting the commandment of God in order
to establish your tradition! ... ‘Whoever reviles father or mother must surely die.

.."But you say, ‘If a man tells his father or his mother, “Whatever you would have
gained from me is Corban”’ (that is given to God) then you no longer permit him to do
anything for his father or mother, thus making void the word of God by your tradition
that you have handed down. And many such things you do.”

**Note**:  **Parable of Tenant of vineyard** ([Matt. 21:33-43](http://localhost:8989/?q=version=ESV%7Creference=Matt.21.33-Matt.21.43&options=VNHUG)) reflects the Jesus' assessment of the
such mindset of the Jewish establishment is rebellious.

**(3) Cessation of Charismata** - *A case of Theological Fallacy!*

**One of the most damaging case in NT era of "breaking of the
Scripture"** done by Hermeneutical/Theological fallacy, against the Jesus' words in [Acts
1:4-5, 8](http://localhost:8989/?q=version=ESV%7Creference=Acts.1.4-Acts.1.5%20Acts.1.8&options=VNHUG), and against the empowerment promised to the Church for carrying out the Great
Commandment -[Mark 16:15 -18](http://localhost:8989/?q=version=ESV%7Creference=Mark.16.15-Mark.16.18&options=VNHUG)).

**This doctrine of "Cessationism" is one major "breaking the Word" in the Church history by various proponents** -*the second to the Gen. 3:1-6* (in my assessment) that teaches:

- The miraculous gifts have indeed ceased in the mainstream church and evangelized
  areas,  but appear in un-reached areas as an aid to spreading the Gospel (**Luther
  and Calvin**, though they were somewhat inconsistent in this position);
- The "sign gifts" such as prophecy, healing, and speaking in tongues ceased with the
  apostles and the finishing of the canon of Scripture (**Richard Gaffin, John F.
  MacArthur and Daniel B. Wallace**);
- No true miracles performed by God today.( **B. B. Warfield, J. Gresham
  Machen, F.N. Lee.)**

**Note**: They admit, they have **NO clear textual support**, except implied in the texts such as -[(Heb. 2:3-4; Gal
3:5;1 Cor. 13:10)](http://localhost:8989/?q=version=ESV%7Creference=1Cor.13.10%20Gal.3.5%20Heb.2.3-Heb.2.4&options=VNHUG), and circumstantial evidence of church history - all the gifts
weaned out with the Apostolic ages. (ref. **Counterfeit Miracles-BB Warfield; Charismatic chaos -John McArthur)**

**(4) Figure of Speech confusion**: Parables & other figure of speeches of prescriptive are being
treated as hyperbole or exaggeration, and being generalized as a "persuasion" thus
depreciate the consequence parts. - e.g. Parables of "Sower; Unfruitful vine
branch, [Matt. 5:30](http://localhost:8989/?q=version=ESV%7Creference=Matt.5.30&options=VNHUG) (if your right arm...),

Comment: The next question is which Scriptures? Do all the texts found at Qumran constitute scripture? Peter and Jude quote Scripture not in the canon. Paul says ALL Scripture is God-breathe/inspired. Jesus answers with non-canonical Scriptures.

Comment: The word “Scripture” is a limiting phrase meaning that which has been set down in writing for us, and the Word of God means that has proceeded from God, not men.  God has said many more things which are not written.  In the canon of Scripture (66 books)  God-breathed and inspired,  the writers under the same guise, were free to make use of materials and pieces of information from non-canonical/holy sources to help illustrate and enforce the truth of God. Loaves of bread and wine selected and used for the Eucharist do not make all the bread and wines from the baker and winery holy.

Comment: I’m not suggesting all ancient texts are God breathe but given the Bible itself has a recommended reading book list THOSE books should be considered. Given the Bible quotes texts from prophets of God about prophecies to come (inferring God breathe words -prophecies) those should be considered. Certainly the Essenes of the Qumran community felt it was important to own and make copies of these Scriptures some of which have been Included in the KJV as an example until 1885 even if not considered canonical it did explain the historical, cosmological and societal backdrop to these Scriptures

Comment: Those extra-canonical copies/sources do provide some valuable/helpful backdrop Infos of the eras of the Scriptures.   Jesus, in John 16:13, introduces His disciples to the ultimate reliable Teacher-Author of the Scripture, and He is the same for all students of the Scripture of all generations.

Comment: If your comment about the Holy Spirit were applied today all Cessationist congregations would have no services, starting with MacArthur. Fortunately for them it’s not an either or situation but unfortunately for them it is supposed to be both Scriptures and the Holy Spirit.

Comment: The Canon of Scripture we inherited with the Holy Spirit helping us is sufficient - w/o extra-Scriptural materials. Jesus has spoken and it stands for every believer for all generations. (To use it or not is the personal prerogative.)
As far as I know, the Cessationist congregations still recite the entire Apostles' Creed, and their Trinitarian Benediction includes "the fellowship of the Holy Spirit."  Despite their dogmatic positions on special gifts of the Holy Spirit, Holy Spirit works among them for His namesake, just as Jesus in His hometown in the face of rejection, He healed a few.

Comment: *“What then, brothers? When you come together, each one has a hymn, a lesson, **a revelation**, a tongue, or an interpretation.”
‭‭1 Cor14:26‬* in the early church everything was done directly through the Holy Spirit, lessons (doctrine in Greek) *“Or was it from you that the word of God came? Or are you the only ones it has reached? If anyone thinks that he is a prophet, or spiritual, he should acknowledge that the things I am writing to you are a command of the Lord.

But all things should be done decently and in order.”
‭‭1 Cor‬ 14:36-37, 40* Even teaching was done supernaturally

Comment: Teaching was not done as it’s done today, purely hermeneutically and exegetically. The Holy Spirit gave revelation and the rest of the congregation consulted the Scriptures to verify it was so. John 7:15 Acts 4:13 Cessationist today deny the Holy Spirits speaks this way. Which makes me wonder where they get their inspiration for their sermons. Notice Paul says his writings are a command from the Lord. It’s all by inspiration and not purely education and reciting